# How to define a variadic macro beside a non-variadic one?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, macros, variadic-macros

The best way is to show it with code. I'm compiling this as a Win32 C++ project under Visual Studio 2017:

```
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Trace outout
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define TRACE(s) ::OutputDebugString(s)
#define TRACE(s, ...) \
    { WCHAR __dbg_buff[1024]; if(SUCCEEDED(::StringCchPrintf(__dbg_buff, _countof(__dbg_buff), s, __VA_ARGS__))) { ::OutputDebugString(__dbg_buff);} else ASSERT(NULL);}
#else
#define TRACE(s) ((void)0)
#define TRACE(s, ...) ((void)0)
#endif
```

The idea is to use the macro in these two types of cases:

```
TRACE(L"value=%02X", v);
TRACE(L"\n");
```

But my macro definition produces this error:

```
warning C4005: 'TRACE': macro redefinition
note: see previous definition of 'TRACE'
error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

What is the way to define it so that it takes both variadic and non-variadic form?

Comment: You can't overload macros. I recommend that you redesign logging and tracing using C++ funcitonality instead, perhaps using stream-like syntax with `<<`.

Comment: Why you need 2 versions? 1st version is just special case of 2nd anyway... I.e. remove `s` from arguments and leave only 2nd version.

Comment: @sklott: With just the 2nd version if I do `TRACE(L"\n");` it will not compile.

Comment: I don't have VC to check, but for GCC something like `#define TRACE(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)` works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that second defintion of TRACE macro redefines the first one, so effectively you have TRACE(x, ...) defined eventually.

Then to use **VA_ARGS** it may be necessary to use it with double '#' prefix. e.g.

```
#define TRACE(fmt, ... )   printf(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Works fine to me with gcc.